# How to pass data from a PHP file back to the original without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to have the output from a PHP file display in the original page containing the form, without having to refresh the page.

I am currently using AJAX to do so but I am not able to pass the value of the submitted PHP file back to the **index.php** page - this needs to be done without having the page refreshed.

**Overall**

- User enters some data and submits the form
- That data is passed to a PHP file through AJAX
- Some pieces of data, which were manipulated through the PHP file, are then echoed out onto the original **index.html** file without the page refreshing

Below you will find the code that I am currently using to try and achieve this.

**index.php**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="hi">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
          });
        });  
      });
    </script>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
    echo "Hello";
    $name = $_POST['hi'];
    echo $name . "This is a test";
?>
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'success' to your object and pass in a parameter to the function. That will hold the results from the php file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

What this does is, on a successful ajax call, stores all of the content sent from the `post.php` file into the `results` variable.' In this case it will be whatever `$name` is and 'This is a test.'

Answer (score 1):

How about this simple solution. Just copy and paste this code into a file called index.php and whatever text you enter in the input field will be outputted by PHP. Hope it helps!.

```
<?php

$data = array();
if(isset($_POST['userText']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
 $data = 'The data you entered is: ' . $_POST['userText'];       
 echo json_encode($data);  
 die();      
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="hi" id = "someID">
<input type="submit" id = "sendInfo">
</form>
<div id = "random"></div>

<script type = "text/javascript">

$("#sendInfo").click(function(){

var someText = document.getElementById("someID").value;
var userText =  JSON.stringify(someText);

$.ajax({
  url: "index.php",
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {userText: userText},
  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $("#random").html(result);
  }
});
return false;

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```